# includeSystemScope Parameter in pom.xml not working

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I'm tring to include a custom jar in my Spingboot application. In my case the additional jar contains a custom font for jasper Report.
This is my "system" decendency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jasperFontOverrides</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperFontOverrides</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/MyriadPro.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

...

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The system package is visible while I debug my application in my IDE but when I'm done and I what to generate the package for production deploy

`mvn install -DskipTests`

[image]

My system package is not included the final jar.

Is there anything missing in my maven configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a multi-module project, you probably need to define the `configuration` section in the **parent** pom.

```
<configuration>
   <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
</configuration>
```

I have spent almost a day debugging this and it seems the configuration set in the child pom is not enough to get this to work. My guess is that the dependencies are calculated early in the build and the `includeSystemScope` option set in the child module is processed too late to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was, I for some reason had the configuration wrapped in execution tag, such as

```
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.package.Main</mainClass>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
```