# How to solve Spring Boot .jar file problem?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, matlab, maven

I have a RESTful API project where I use Spring Boot Maven. I'm also processing in Matlab with a jar file. I converted this project to .jar file, but running it with `java -jar demo.jar` closes after running. I got some errors. However, since it was a restful API, it had to remain open so that I could access the APIs.

Java : Java 11

Matlab: R2018a, JRE 1.8
pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.16</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <cholSolver.path>C:\Users\user\Desktop\PDTO-Project\pdtopolys\cholSolver.jar</cholSolver.path>
        <javabuilder.path>C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar</javabuilder.path>     
         
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>mtj</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>peridynamics</groupId>
            <artifactId>cholSolver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${cholSolver.path}</systemPath>
        </dependency>    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mathworks</groupId>
        <artifactId>javabuilder</artifactId>
        <version>R2018a</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${javabuilder.path}</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version> 
</dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After running:java -jar demo.jar, a few errors and closed:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.16)

2023-10-02 10:33:45.924  INFO 25648 --- [           main] peridynamics.demoApp                     : Starting demoApp v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.8 on IMC-RYILDIZ with PID 25648 (C:\Users\suuser\Desktop\PDTO-Deneme\PDTO-Project\pdtopolys\fea\target\demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by rozerin.yildiz in C:\Users\suuser\Desktop\PDTO-Deneme\PDTO-Project\pdtopolys\fea)
2023-10-02 10:33:45.928  INFO 25648 --- [           main] peridynamics.demoApp                     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-02 10:33:46.798  INFO 25648 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-10-02 10:33:46.807  INFO 25648 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-10-02 10:33:46.807  INFO 25648 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.80]
2023-10-02 10:33:46.889  INFO 25648 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-10-02 10:33:46.890  INFO 25648 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 906 ms
2023-10-02 10:33:46.940  WARN 25648 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beso3D_PD': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [peridynamics.Beso3D_PD] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@1ed6993a]
2023-10-02 10:33:46.940  INFO 25648 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-10-02 10:33:46.956  INFO 25648 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.        
2023-10-02 10:33:46.974 ERROR 25648 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beso3D_PD': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [peridynamics.Beso3D_PD] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@1ed6993a]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1302) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16] 
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at peridynamics.demoApp.main(demoApp.java:11) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]     
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]  
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [peridynamics.Beso3D_PD] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@1ed6993a]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mathworks/toolbox/javabuilder/MWException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
```

How to fix these problems?

Comment: well, the warning clearly states the problem. The library you imported tried to use reflection which was not allowed and caused your application to shutdown

Comment: Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: This other thread seems to solve the same issue, so you could refer to it https://stackoverflow.com/a/68964308/16034206

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot - An illegal reflective access operation has occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956945/spring-boot-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred)

Comment: @experimentunit1998X  I tried  `java --illegal-access=deny peridynamics.demoApp -jar demo.jar` but i get could not find the main class error. This is the main class, i also checked in Manifest.mf.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Btw, I run ` java --illegal-access=deny  -jar demo.jar`. I couldn't see warning messages. However the system closing.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I edited the question. Could you check it?

Comment: Not sure if you tried this before? https://www.baeldung.com/java-illegal-reflective-access#:~:text=And%2C%20to%20add%20opens%20to%20all%20unnamed%20modules%2C%20we%20can%20use%20the%20ALL%2DUNNAMED but if ALL_UNNAMED doesnt work, maybe you can try naming to the specific peridynamics module?

Comment: You could also see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/transition-from-java-8-to-java-11#:~:text=The%20warning%20in%20the,named%20ALL%2DUNNAMED.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X difference between Matlab java version and the project java version be a problem? There is a jar file that uses Matlab, the jar file's Java version is Java 11 and Matlab version is R2018a JRE 1.8. I thought the version difference could make these errors. What do you think? For instance, what about updating the jar file Matlab version (R2023a Java 11)?

Comment: that could help. why dont you try it out>

Comment: I am gonna try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. As you can see in the pom.xml file, i added some `<scope></scope>`. And also as you can see in the errors it couldn't find `javabuilder`. After adding this in plugin:

```
<configuration>
   <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
</configuration>
```

the problem was solved successfully.

Reference: https:https://stackoverflow.com/a/72439269/17051811